# Nokogiri Ruby - Remove the <!DOCTYPE ... > from the output html

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am parsing an html file using nokogiri and modifying it and then outputting it to a file like this:

```
htext= File.open(inputOpts.html_file).read
h_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(htext)
File.open(outputfile, 'w+')  do |file|
  file.write(h_doc)
end
```

The output file contains the first line as:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

I do not want this because I am embedding the html in a different file and this tag is causing issues.

Question is how do I remove this from h_doc.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could parse your HTML as a [`DocumentFragment`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/DocumentFragment.html):

```
h_doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(htext)
```

When calling `to_s` or `to_html` on a fragment the doctype line will be omitted, as will the `<html>` and `<body>` tags that Nokogiri adds if they aren’t already present.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your needs. If all you need is the body then

```
h_doc.at_xpath("//body") #this will just pull the data from the <body></body> tags
```

If you need to collect the `<head>` too and just avoid the `<DOCTYPE>` then

```
#this will capture everything between the <head></head> and <body></body> tags
h_doc.xpath("//head") + h_doc.xpath("//body")
```

So something like this

```
h_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(input_opts.html_file))
File.open(outputfile,'w+') do |file|
  #for just <body>
  file << h_doc.at_xpath("//body").to_s
  #for <head> and <body>
  file << (h_doc.xpath("//head") + h_doc.xpath("//body")).to_s
end
```

Notice for `body` I used `#at_xpath` as this will return a `Nokogiri::Element` but when combining them I used `#xpath` becuase this will return a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`. No need to worry this part is just for the combination and the html will come out the same e.g. `h_doc.at_xpath("//head").to_s == h_doc.xpath("//head").to_s #=> true`

Comment: if he wants to embed it, this is probably the right solution

Comment: I managed to solve this same challenge with help from this answer. I'll more detail in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore the first line when reading the input file:

```
htext= File.readlines(inputOpts.html_file)[1..-1].join
h_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(htext)
File.open(outputfile, 'w+')  do |file|
  file.write(h_doc)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this with both an `HTML::Document` and an `HTML::DocumentFragment`.

- For background, I'm using Nokogiri to parse and modify "templates", "partials" and/or "components" of HTML. This means that the files I encounter are not valid HTML documents. They are, instead, pieces of an HTML document that gets put together by the framework I'm using.
- For reference, `HTML::Document` adds the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration and also wraps your document into `<html>` and `<body>` entities if they are not already present in your document. Similarly, `HTML::DocumentFragment` will wrap your fragment with `<p>` entity.

Rather than spending too much time digging into the Nokogiri library code to understand where these additional entities were being, I decided to accept to this opinionated implementation and work around it.

#### Solution

Here's how I write out my modified HTML:

```
html_str = doc.xpath("//body").children.to_html(encoding: 'UTF-8')
File.open(_filename, 'w') {|f| f.write(html_str)}
```

#### Final Word

This seems harder than it should be. I even tried using the `SaveOptions` setting `save_with: Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION` to no avail.

In any case, while this solution is a bit kludgey for my liking, it works.